# sql if parameter is true, add a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a long stored procedure with cross joins and left joins. I have several parameters in this table. On the last two left joins, I want to add a conditional where clause based on a parameter.

I will call this parameter `@NonCAT` which basically category code. The where clause that I am trying to implement just weeds out the non-category codes. The codes for the non-category codes are as follows:

```
CATCOD IN ('0', '114', '214', '314', '414', '614')
```

So any of those numbers in the `CATCOD` column are considered noncat codes. 
Otherwise, if they are included, like if they are not in a where clause, they are considered cat codes. so here is my where clause in the last two left joins:

```
AND CASE
       WHEN il.CATCOD IN ('0', '114', '214', '314', '414', '614') 
          THEN 'NonCAT'
          ELSE 'CAT'
    END = @NonCAT
```

This works just fine if I am trying to extract the category codes the `@NonCAT` variable is just a `varchar(20)` and it's set to 'NonCAT' as its value for now for the sake of testing. With the where clause in place, I am going to extract the non-cat codes.

I want a conditional statement, say if the variable `@NonCAT = 'CAT'`, I want to omit that where clause. How do I go about doing this? I have tried various case statements and it's harder than it sounds. Thanks so much for the help.

Edit: I tried using `iff` statement in a where clause for example,

```
AND (IF @NonCAT = 'NonCAT'
     BEGIN
         CASE
            WHEN il.CATCOD IN ('0', '114', '214', '314', '414', '614') 
               THEN 'NonCAT'
               ELSE 'CAT'
         END = @NonCAT
     END)
```

Seems like that doesn't work. I can use an IF statement at the very begging of the code as a flag but that doesn't seem very efficient because I would have to rewrite the whole thing without a where clause if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
WHERE   ( ( @nonCAT = 'nonCAT' AND il.CATCOD IN ('0', '114', '214', '314', '414', '614') )
      OR ( (ISNULL(@nonCAT,'') <> 'nonCAT' ))
```

Comment: Hi I think this is close but the second logic, ISNULL(il.CATCOD,'NULL') NOT IN ('0', '114', '214', '314', '414', '614') I actually want to include everything in that column if the variable @NonCAT <> 'NonCAT'. I tried modifying it to: 
and ( atNonCAT = 'NonCAT' AND il.CATCOD IN ('0', '114', '214', '314', '414', '614') )
OR ( (ISNULL(atNonCAT,'') <> 'NonCAT' AND il.CATCOD = il.CATCOD ) )

So basically, I want all the CATCOD column to output when the variable atNonCAT doesn't equal to 'NonCAT'

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the CATCOD column is an int column so I simply removed the 'NULL' in ISNULL(il.CATCOD,'NULL')

Comment: @Lisbon try again.